# Two factor authentication and plausible deniability for disk encryption

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, multi-factor

Can you prove, for the most common disk encryption programs like Veracrypt or LUKS/dmcrypt, that a second factor like a yubikey or a keyfile on a USB disk is required? If this is not the case is there anything the end user could do? Like some configuration options?

In some countries there are key disclosure laws and in case plausible deniability would be possible you could just claim the dog ate it. They probably still won't believe you, but anyways.

Comment: (just my opinion, but "been used" was more clear ... when reading now, I was thinking "of course a second factor is not required to use LUKS etc., what do you want to prove there")

Comment: @deviantfan i hear you, but I was really confused in the other wording. Suggestions?

Comment: "has been used" does not imply that it is required, just that someone tried

Comment: Well, also true, I hope the second part about the dog makes it more clear on if/how the second factor is/has been used/required ;)

Comment: Veracryot has a page about the plausable deniability of hidden volumes. https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Plausible%20Deniability.html that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: No a Yubikey is **not** required. You don't have to do anything except saying "there is no encrypted volume" and "You are mistaken". That's the point of plausible deniability, the attacker cannot know whether encrypted data even exists.

Comment: @Daisetsu Not really what I am looking for. I know about plausible deniabilty for encryption, but I'm more interested in how to plausible deny the second factor. Bakuriu, This is true but lets say you have a dog full of encrypted disks each having LUKS or Veracrypt header plus you have a part of the disk where your bootloader and kernel + initrd resides and the rest of the disk looks like encrypted data. So guess what could be in this part which looks like encrypted data. Yes, I know you can't prove that there is something in there or that it is encrypted at all, but it is quite improbable.

Comment: I read that [Plausible Deniability is Theoretically Useless](https://defuse.ca/truecrypt-plausible-deniability-useless-by-game-theory.htm) and you might regret not using it

Comment: @Xen2050 It depends in your threat model. Also that write-up is kind of stupid.

Comment: @forest True, in most situations & countries you're generally "innocent until proven guilty," and it's a slightly strange example, but the bottom line is if you can't prove you *don't* have hidden encrypted data, then you could be screwed

Comment: @Xen2050 I can't think of any non-contrived scenario where that would be the case, otherwise literally _everyone_ is screwed because even your old encrypted swap file in unallocated space could be a TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt volume. In reality, it's quite useful e.g. at border inspections. They can demand a password but they aren't going to beat it out of you under a bright light like in the movies.

Answer (score 1):

**It is impossible to tell if a keyfile is required.** There is no difference, from an attacker's perspective, between being unable to decrypt a drive because they are exactly one letter off in the password, and because they are missing an entire keyfile. All they know is that they are unable to decrypt it. In fact, if I were to give you a hard drive that has truly random (very high entropy at 8 bits per byte) data on it, you would be unable to tell if I had encrypted it with a password, with a password and a keyfile, or even if it is not encrypted at all and was just wiped.

When you use a keyfile, it is mixed with the password. This is then is used to derive the key that decrypts the header to retrieve the master key. A keyfile can thus be thought of as an extension of your password.

Comment: @forest actually, you could conclude that 'random' data hadn't been encrypted if the entropy was low, apparent randomness isn't just enough - but I get the point in answer to the question